# Objective C SQLite insert statements not working database is locked

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert

I need to figure out why I am getting the "database is locked" error.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)insertQuery:(NSString*)query db:(sqlite3*)db
{
    sqlite3_stmt *stmnt = NULL;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmnt, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(stmnt) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmnt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Before this method is used I create an sqlite3 object like so:

```
sqlite3 *db = NULL;
int rc = 0;

rc = sqlite3_open_v2([[self getDbFilePath] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"Unable to open");
}
```

I don't seem to have a problem opening the database, but I do get the error message from my NSLog in the insertQuery method that says "database is locked."

The query NSString looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Properties (ID,Name) VALUES (1234,"A Name")
```

Comment: Do you have another thread doing a query? Is this insert function called while another connection is open, such as while enumerating the result of a `SELECT`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I checked my code pretty thoroughly. It seems that my other methods are closing the sqlite3 object. How could I be sure of this? Is there a method to check if the db is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reworking some of my code. When I create my SQLite class I use the same sqlite3 variable throughout instead of making a new one and opening and closing it in every method. I just keep the sqlite3 open the entire time.